# Multi threading to execute multiple makefiles

Tags: multithreading, makefile

The problem is it takes lot of time(20-30 minutes) to build our application.

There are around 5000+ files and the code is divided into various subsystems, which can be built independently. Each subsystem has its own makefile.

My question is: Is it possible to create a thread for each makefile so that all the subsystems are built in parallel and subsequently run a makefile to merge them all?

If it is possible, how to proceed about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the parallelism facilities of make. With `-j number` make will run `number`recipes simultaneously.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel) for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Using `make -j` (as TheMorph says) is definitely the way to go.

However, this works best if a single make process can see the build dependencies and figure out what to parallelize. It sounds like you have a recursive Makefile system though, which is [considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) (warning: that link is a PDF).

It's generally hard to run recursive makes in parallel, because the dependencies between different subsystems aren't really understood by the top-level make.

So, your best bet may be to fix recursive makefiles first, and *then* take full advantage of `-j`.

[This](http://mischasan.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/non-recursive-make-gmake-part-1-the-basic-gnumakefile-layouts/) is an example of writing a non-recursive make system. Note that you still have a makefile in every directory where you currently have one, and each makefile still manages the same targets, and each subdirectory can still be built independently.  The difference is that a toplevel build includes all the subdirectory makefiles into a single dependency graph, which allows it to parallize much more aggressively.